# Performing action on change focus

Tags: android, button, view, focus

How can be performed an action on change focus over a view? in particular I would change some attributes of LinearLayout view when the focus is on a certain button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think onFocusChangeListener may help you:

[onFocusChanged(boolean, int, android.graphics.Rect)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)